# Exiting from a powershell menu

Tags: powershell

I've created a powershell menu script but occasionally I don't want to use the menu function I have created I want to come out and run a custom command, or even better add a menu feature which allows me to write a custom command.

Can anyone help me achieve this please?

```
write-host  "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" 
write-host          "Exchange Online Management"                                 
write-host                                                            
write-host          "Press 1: To assign Full Access To A Mailbox"              
write-host          "Press 2: Get Mailbox Size"
write-host          "Press 3: Custom Exchange Command"
write-host          "Press Q: To Leave Exchange Management"                                     
write-host
write-host
write-host "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
$SM2 = Read-Host "Please Make A Selection"
Switch ($SM2) {
'1'{ 
DO something
}
'2' {
$Mailboxuser = read-host "Who's Mailbox are you trying to query?"
Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailboxuser | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount
}
'3' {
return
}
'Q' {
Remove-PSSession $Session
return
}
}
}
until ($SM -eq 'Q')
```

Comment: Readers might want to see some of the attempted code you have. Please add it to your question, so anyone willing to help has something to work with.

Comment: Add a menu option with the `exit` command?

Comment: Depending on your code, you could use `break`, but it would be helpful to see what you have written.

Comment: @Shabbaranks you'll need to edit your question to add code, it doesn't work very well in comments

Comment: Thanks just did it :)

Comment: Thanks guys tried break and it just loops back to the menu selection exit closes down powershell.

Comment: Why does your Q logic not work? That is your way of exiting the loop? I would also highly recommend the [PowerShell choice system](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Im not sure if Im confusing the question, the Q does work which exits me from the powershell command completely. What I want to do is exit from the menu system so I can input a custom command on the fly if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell console window is closing after it has finished executing your script.

You can get around this by running another powershell process with your script:

```
'Q' {
Remove-PSSession $Session    
& powershell
}
```

The other option is to create a shortcut to your script and add the `-NoExit` switch, which stops the window from closing when the script is finished.

`PowerShell -NoExit "C:\folder\script.ps1"`